# django | called method not working

Tags: python, django

in my django project , when browser requests to call a method (here : addpricelist) , with no error , it doesn't run ! i mean it should print"&&&&.." but nothing happens! does anybody know why ??
if you need complete source code go [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7933091/)(views.py)
view.py:

```
 def addpricelist(request):
        print "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& "
        print request.POST.get()
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

url.py:

```
url(r'^addpricelist',roomviews.addpricelist),
```

server log :

```
**[02/Aug/2014 12:38:58] "POST /addpricelist HTTP/1.1" 200 8941**
```

Comment: print in django view have no effect

Comment: django is web framework to display msg is restrict to either in log or your template

Comment: The print may or may not print anything on the console. Depends on the server it is running on. But it will definitely NOT print anything on the browser, if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: i wanted to print in server not browser !

Comment: As I mentioned above -- there is NO guarantee a print would work on the "server". It MAY print on the console in which the server is running, but that's not guaranteed either.

Comment: @slim_ch: "print" behaves the same way in a django view as in any Python code: it prints to the process's stdout. What this stdout is depends on the process itself (embedded dev server, apache + mod_wsgi, nginx+gunicorn or whatever).

Comment: 1. does your view render correctly ? and 2. how are you running your app ? (dev server, apache+mod_wsgi, nginx+gunicorn, something else ?). But anyway: you should use Python's `logging` module instead - unless it's for a quick one-shot debug on Django's embedded dev server, and even then...

Comment: Totally OT but I had a look at your full code and you should really take time to properly learn Django (like using `ModelForm` etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the problem is with **routing and addressing urls**!!
to solve,change the urls and defs in veiw.py

```
url(r'^pla',roomviews.plistadd),
```

so my experience is when everything is wired just,just think about routing!when something should be called but it didn't,maybe you have dialed a wrong number ;)

Answer (score 0):

why you  don't render the message in your template:

```
def addpricelist(request,**Kargs):
    msg="&&&&&&&&&&&&& "    
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'msg':msg})
```

index.html just add

{{msg}}

Comment: no , there's another problem !! the method is called but nothing happens !! i mean how even it's possible for method to being called without any error and then the first line (print) doesn't run!seems wired , hah ?

Comment: you don't have any error but like i said print is have no permission to display msg in django